# Fredholmness of formal selfadjoint operator $AA^*$ and Fredholmenss of $A$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Hilbert spaces with respective inner products $\langle , \rangle_{X,Y}$. Let $A:X \rightarrow Y$ be a bounded linear operator. Assume there is a non-degenerate sesquilinear product $(,)$ on $Y$. Take $y \in Y$, and define the map
$l_y : x' \in X \mapsto (A x', y)$.
Assume this last map is bounded, then by Riesz's theorem, there exists a unique $x \in X$ such that $l_y(x') = \langle x' ,x \rangle_X$. We define the formal adjoint of $A$, denoted as $A^*$ by $A^*(y) = x$. Note that this coincides with the adjoint of $A$ when $(,) = \langle , \rangle_{Y}$.

Is it true that if $AA^*$ is a Fredholm operator then $A$ is Fredholm as well?

A particular case I am interested take $d: L^2_k([0,1]) \rightarrow L^2_{k-1}([0,1])$ (where $L^2_k$ denotes the Sobolev space with $k$ weak derivatives in $L^2$) and take $(,)$ as the $L^2([0,1])$ inner product.

Comment: What do you mean by *formal adjoint of $A$* in this context?

Comment: I  mean in the sense of the second line, the one that satisfies: $\int_X (Bf,g) = \int_X (f,B^*g)$ for all $f, g$, where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is a non-degenerate bilinear (or complex in one variable in case it maps to $\mathbb{C}$) map. I guess  I am assuming that it exists. But solving it for the specific case of the $A$ given above would be already helpful. thanks

Comment: - Why do you make a difference between adjoint and formal adjoint?
- Don't you mean $(f,g)=\bar f g$? Or do you want another inner product?
- What is $L^2_1$?

Comment: yes, I meant that one, I should have specified that (I have edited it now). $L^2_1$ is the Sobolev space with a first weak derivative in $L^2$

Comment: You still have to say what you mean by formal adjoint and whether $A^*$ is different from $A'$.

Comment: thanks @JanBohr I have edited the question as it was too vague, I hope it is now clearer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80757/discussion-between-inquisitor-and-jan-bohr).

Comment: I do not think either $d$ or the Laplacian is a Fredholm operator on $L^2_k(\Bbb R)$. The problem is that these are translation-invariant operators with kernel. Consider a smooth function $f_n$ which is equal to $1$ on $[-n, n]$ and is supported on, let's say, $[-n-\epsilon, n+\epsilon]$; we may as well assume that these functions are always the same on $[-n-1/2, -n+1/2]$. Then $\|df_n\|_{L^2}$ is constant in $n$, as is $\|\Delta f_n\|_{L^2}$. However, $\|f_n\|_{L^2_k} \to \infty$. This contradicts the inequality $\|v\| \leq C(\|Tv\| + \|\Pi v\|)$, where $\Pi v$ is projection to the kernel.

Comment: true! I will edit the post, thanks